# How to filter by a list of date ranges in Spark SQL with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Suppose we have a data frame called df, with a column named "DATE". I know that we can filter the data frame by a date range with `df.filter(col("DATE").between(startDate, endDate))`, or filter by multiple date ranges with `df.filter(col("DATE").between(startDate, endDate) ||  col("DATE").between(startDate1, endDate1) || ...)`.

But what if we have a list of date ranges like [[startDate1, endDate1], [startDate2, endDate2], ... , [startDaten, endDaten]], the number of `n` can be any number. Is there an efficient way to filter the data frame by all these date ranges?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way:

```
val ranges = initilaze your ranges
val singleFilter = ranges.reduce { (d1, d2) => 
  col("DATE").between(d1.startDate, d1.endDate) || 
  col("DATE").between(d2.startDate, d2.endDate)
}
dataframe.filter(singleFilter)
```

Comment: If the data ranges are overlapping then there could be duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to initialize the ranges? Is ranges a dataframe too?

Comment: When using `reduce` for ranges, seems the type does not match between `col("DATE").between(d1.startDate, d1.endDate)` and `d2`. Therefore, the `singleFilter` may not work - but it depends on the format of `ranges` too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution with map and reduce.

Let the date ranges be 
`val dateRanges: List[(String, String)] = List((startDate1, endDate1), (startDate2, endDate2), (startDate3, endDate3))`

`val results = df.filter(
dateRanges.map(range => col("Date").between(range._1, range._2))
.reduce((df1, df2) => df1 || df2))`

Here, first each date range is mapped to a partition of dataframe using `map`, then different partitions of dataframes are joined together by `reduce`.

But does anyone know the efficiency of this method? Certainly keep joining two pieces of data set will not be the optimal way.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I mentioned. but you do map here first then reduce. I do the reduce directly.